# ARM Neon: Performance vld4.u8 vs 4x vld1.u8

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

What is the fastest between four times vld1 and once vld4. Obviously, loaded data is not the same but if I have the choice, what is best or is it the same?

```
pld[in]
vld1.u8 { d0 }, [in]!
vld1.u8 { d1 }, [in]!
vld1.u8 { d2 }, [in]!
vld1.u8 { d3 }, [in]!
```

vs.

```
pld[in]
vld4.u8 { d0, d1, d2, d3 }, [in]!
```

Comment: You realise `vld1` can still take a list of up to 4 consecutive registers, right?

Comment: No, I didn't know :-( I feel like stupid. I read the documentation thoroughly now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vld1.u8 {d0, d1, d2, d3}, [in]!` will generally be faster than or equal to `vld4.u8` on the same list.  This is because `vld4` may have to permute the data after it's loaded to get it into the right registers.

Even if it does have to more work, that extra cost may be hidden behind other factors so it's not necessarily a big deal.

Comment: FWIW, looking at some timings `vld4` vs. 4-register `vld1` total latency is 9 vs. 8 cycles on Cortex-A9, 9 vs. 6 cycles on Cortex-A72, but as you rightly say that's easily lost in a well-scheduled pipeline.